# autocompletion pop up menu in sublime text 3 doesn't display

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

I have Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu and the ctrl+space to bring the autocompletion menu does not work. I tried to set it in the user key binding but it still does not work.

I then installed the SublimeCodeIntel package, but I have the same issue. I can manually bring the pop-up menu up. Even with the ctrl+shift+space for SublimeCodeIntel nothing works.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First save your document as css or which ever format you want your browser to read it as. Sublime Text will recognize the type of markup/programming language you are using and auto complete accordingly.